# Modelize a road networks out of GPS data

Tags: python

I have a lot of GPS data from vehicles driving around on a private property which is not mapped anywhere.

I would like to model the road network using this GPS data ; That would allow me to check where those vehicles are live by snapping their position back on the road we've just modeled.

I have a big time finding resources online on how this can be done in python for instance. I would think that this is a problem that has been "solved" already and that libraries would be available. Can anyone drive me through the available resources?

Comment: osmnx based on OpenStreetMap Data format does this https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx